# SoapFault exception: [Client] looks like we got no XML document

Tags: php, soap

I've hit an issue with the PHP SoapClient.

Here is the code:

```
$obj = new SoapClient(WEBSERVICE_ADDRESS,array('trace' => 1,'encoding'=>'utf-8', 'exceptions' => 0)); 

$res_obj = ($obj->searchTextBySummaryAndDescription($params));
```

`$res_obj`  is a object. It includes a bug list. Every bug has details such as `Bugdescription`. The issue is that one of the Bug Description has a special character "`←`", so I see an error as per my question's title when I try to run eg: `print $res_obj;`

Answer (score 0):

I got this:

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] looks like we got
>   no XML document...

and, I change in php.ini file row

> ;always_populate_raw_post_data = -1

with this:

> always_populate_raw_post_data = -1

e.g. without **;**

Answer (score -1):

try adding

```
error_reporting( 0 ) ;
```

to the top of the page.